# How would a graph with edge connectivity 4 ,vertex connectivity 3 and degree of each vertex greater than equal to 5 look like?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is there any standard algorithm to solve this problem?
Or it needs to be solved using trial and error approach?

Comment: not entirely sure, but can you construct and 4-edge-conn 3-vertex-conn graph and let each vertex be a mini-$K_5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really an algorithm, but brute force is not necessary.

Think of it this way:

- You want your graph to have edge connectivity $4$, so put in a place where $4$ edges go between two otherwise-disconnected parts of the graph.
- You want your graph to have vertex connectivity $3$, so put in a place (probably the same place) where $3$ vertices of one part of the graph are all that connect it to the other part.
- You want high degree, and you want the two parts of the graph to not have smaller edge or vertex cuts, so we might as well make them complete graphs to not have to worry about that.

Thinking along these lines, we might come up with the following graph:

[image: Example]

(The two parts probably did not really need to be $K_9$'s, but I get carried away sometimes.)

Comment: Thanx a lot!!
That was really helpful..!!